Does a shape exist in a 3D (x,y,z) space such that you can project it on to two planes like (y,x) (z,x) and the projection will be a circle
Say you have a path, orbit or general shape in a 3D space (x,y,z), and you would like the projection onto any two planes sharing one variable to be a perfect circle.
In other words, the projection of the shape onto the (x,y) & (z,y), or (z,x) & (y,x) etc should result in a circle.
How would you construct the expression to describe such a shape, using a combination of sinusoidal functions and constants.
To plot a circle you can simply plot sinusoidal functions phase shifted by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The image below consits of $cos(\tau),cos(\tau+\frac{\pi}{2}), cos(\tau + \pi)$.

For the origin of this problem the $x$ and $y$ functions would be coupled in some form, while the $z$ function would not be. They would vary over time. I am mostly looking for some general solution to the above decribed problem. However I can edit and post the exact equations (of motion in my case) that lead me down this path.
This has generally not been my area of study, and I am unsure if this (or similar problems) have a common name. I have search around the internet, and here - without finding what I am looking for. Thanks in advance.
Edit: Thats not a sphere

It is a sphere.

Correct, I may have worded this poorly. I am wondering if there exist any other shape that would result in this, not have to result in a circle in every possible projection, just with the constraint of sharing one axis.

What's the difference (if any) between "the projection of the shape onto the (x,y) & (z,y) planes, or (z,x) & (y,x) planes, is a circle" and "the projection of the shape onto the (x,y) & (z,y) & (z,x) planes is a circle"?

@ZachariasAndersson, If you mean projection on only one plane, for example xy plane then it could be ellipsoid  it's major axis perpendicular on xy plane, or a cone its axis perpendicular on xy plane.

They key to the problem here for me is that it must be onto two planes, and they should share one axis.
